# plupload - how to access ajax response on Error event

Tags: jquery, upload, plupload

I'm working on jquery plupload plugin. this plugin has number of events that i used some of them and are working fine. At this time i need to use `Error` event and access ajax response in this event. how can i do this? here is my uploader widget:

```
$("#uploader").plupload({
        init: {
            BeforeUpload: function(up, file) {

                   //some functions
            },
            FileUploaded: function(up, file, object) {
                // some functions

            },
            UploadComplete: function(up) {

            },
            QueueChanged: function() {
                //some functions
            },
            Error: function(/* what is the parameter? */){
              //How can i access ajax response here?
            }

        },
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'html5',
        url: pageVars.contextPath + "/file/uploadDo",
        // Maximum file size
        max_file_size: '20000mb',
        chunk_size: '10mb',



        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
            {title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png"},
            {title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip,rar,iso"},
            {title: "PDF files", extensions: "pdf"},
            {title: "EXE files", extensions: "exe"},
            {title: "Music", extensions: "mp3"},
        ],
        // Rename files by clicking on their titles
        rename: true,
        // Sort files
        sortable: true,
        // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
        dragdrop: true,
        // Views to activate
        views: {
            list: false,
            thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
            active: 'thumbs'
        },


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the plupload demo, you can handle error event like that:

**Upload page** (js script, examples/custom.html):

```
Error: function(up, err) {
        document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
    }
```

**PHP** (server side upload handler, examples/upload.php):

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
}
```